# 2013 displays entire claims string instead of username

Tags: 2013, claims

In some parts of a migrated 2013 (from 2010) the entire claims string `Wes, Johan,#i:0#.w|xx\johwes01,#Johan.Wes@xx.se,#Johan.Wes@xx.se,#Wes, Johan (2015-03-24 10:18): ...`  is showing.

This is in the default interface, nothing customized. The SPWebApplication MigrateUsers and ProvisionGlobally methods have been run.

Any advice?

Thanks

Updated with image of gui

[image]

Comment: why does it bother you?

Comment: @Gwny It is displayed like that in the 2013 gui, not very practical

Comment: Do you have a value for this user in the User Profile Property *Name* field?

Comment: @BennySkogberg I'll check it but the names are displayed correctly elseware